# Ruby model display only data where key=value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a rails project and have a model `customers` and `suppliers`. I have a sqlite database table called `people`. In the customers model I only want to show data from the people table where `type=customer` and the supplier to only show data from the people table where `type=supplier`

Its crucial I use the same table for both the models. How would I make the customer model only display `type=customer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `default_scope`?

In Customer

```
default_scope where(:type => 'customer')
```

In Supplier

```
default_scope where(:type => 'supplier')
```

Or, you can use `Single table inheritance`. Find it [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)

Answer (score 3):

Go for single table inheritance.
[single table inheritance](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/03/rails-single-table-inheritance/)

where u need to inherit `customers` and `suppliers` from `people`.